# How can you read the current value of an input in an onkeypress method in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have:

```
<input onkeypress="@Foo" />
```

and:

```
@functions
{
    void Foo(UIKeyboardEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

How do I pass, or otherwise retrieve, the value of the input in the handler method?

Answer (score 28):

Unfortunately, you need **oninput** event to update the bound variable.

```
@value
<input type="text" @bind="@value" @oninput="@(ui => { value = (string) ui.Value);})" />

@functions {
    string value;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: The parenthesis after ui.Value has no matching parenthesis so you should probably remove it to make it correct. Otherwise it works as intended, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

For people searching about this, you can implement this with .net core 3.1 to handle on keypress event on Blazor.

```
<input value="@stringValue" @oninput="(EventArgs) => {SetValue(EventArgs.Value.ToString()); DoSomethingElse();}"/>

@code {
    string stringValue = "";

    private void SetValue(string Value)
    {
        stringValue = int.Parse(Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

"KeyboardEvent events just indicate what interaction the user had with a key on the keyboard at a low level". In order to access the text input, you should use the input event or change event instead. In Blazor, right now the input event is wrapped by the change event; that is, your code can access new values only after the input element has lost focus. What you should do, however, is define a property which is bound to the input element and can be accessed in your code for retrieval purposes:

```
protected string MyInput {get; set;}

<input type="text" bind="@MyInput" />
```

The above binding is internally based on the change event, not the input event (again, right now it is not possible in Blazor)

Comment: So it's completely impossible to retrieve the value as you type?

Comment: Yes, right now you can't do that in Blazor. However, you may use RxJS observables or rx.Net ( I believe this is the name) instead. SteveSanderson has already referred to this and said that presently they are not going to deal with this need as well as the mechanism of throttling, which he suggested should be done by the developer. As you know, the input event of itself is not enough to implement your objective properly: you need throttling. This mechanism is available on the fly in  RxJS observables and rx.Net. Hope this helps... If you believe my answer helps you, please give me the credit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the 'oninput' event instead. This event is called every time the value of the Input-element changes. It takes one parameter which is a UIChangeEventArgs that contains a Value property with the Input-elements current value.
E.g.

```
<input type="text" oninput="@((ui) => { Foo((string)ui.Value);})"/>

@function {
    void Foo(string s)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `oninput` event.

```
<input type="text" @oninput="UpdateText"/>

The text is <label>@Text</label>

@code {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    private void UpdateText(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = e.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was having a hard time on this as all the others would not work or would just work for the first keypress and not the rest.  I started at the top answer with (with 23 up votes) all the way to the last one, this one with no votes (so far since it is newer) and yours is the only one that works. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Best solution here, updates real time, regardless of how input was submitted

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the input to update the bound value in real time, you can use:

```
<input @bind-value="foo" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
```

If you specifically want to associate your event with keyboard event args, then something like this will work:

```
<input @bind-value="foo" @onkeypress="HandleKeyPress" />
@bar
@code {
    string foo;
    string bar;
    void HandleKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        bar = $"You just pressed {args.Key}!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Searched for the same thing.

Right answer for Blazor WASM (.NET 5) is:

```cs
@code {
   public string OurField { get; set; }
}

<Element @bind-ElementFieldName="OurField" />
```

Example for `TextEdit` from `Blazorise`:

```cs
@code {
   private string Login { get; set; }
}

<TextEdit @bind-Text="Login"></TextEdit>
```

Comment: Worked with `<input @bind-value="FormUsername" type="username" />`, however the value of `FormUsername` only updates when the user unfocuses the input box

Answer (score 0):

I am using .NET 6 with Blazor Server and this is what worked with the updates Blazor has made since the original date of this question

My code gets the text from the input element as the user types and uses it to search my data grid.

```
<input @oninput="@(SearchDataGrid)" type="text"/>
```

The SearchDataGrid function looks like so:

```
private async Task SearchDataGrid(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        string? userInput = e.Value?.ToString();

        //Logic to implement search//
        if (DataGrid is null) return;
        await DataGrid.SearchAsync(userInput);
    }
```

Be sure to include this at the top of your .razor file

```
@using ChangeEventArgs = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs
```

If you wish to give it some styling, you can utilize the input groups from the Forms section of Bootstrap ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/)) and it'll look something like this:

[image: Screenshot of styled input element for search purposes]

Here's the HTML I used for that:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text e-icons e-search"></div>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" @oninput="@(SearchTreeArea)" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Additionally, it's worth noting that Microsoft's documentation lays out which class are currently supported in .NET 8 based on the type of event you wish to handle. For more information, you can read up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0)!

[image: Supported EventArgs]

Answer (score -5):

For simplicity you can use this code:

```
<input bind-value-oninput="@stringValue"/>

@functions {
string stringValue;
}
```

Comment: you should use bind-value and bind-value:event="oninput" to handle keypress down event.